Как передать массив методом POST из HTML-формы?
пытаюсь настроить передачу методом POST нескольких элементов в массив из HTML формы, но передаются только первые значения
{
  "d1_id": "380450",
  "idts": "295205011",
  "rl": "1",
  "task_id": "Asdfghs="
}

Пример:
Сформировать массив idts для отправки,
<form class="row g-3 needs-validation" name="assign_ts" id = "assign_ts" action="/assignts" method="post" novalidate>
{% for i in range (0, items.cts,1) %}
<div class="col-md-3 element{{ i }}">
<label for="validationCustom02{{ i }}" class="form-label">Транспорт</label>
    <div class="input-group{{ i }}">
        <select form = "assign_ts" name = "idts" class="single-select form-select selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="validationCustom02{{ i }}" required>
        <option selected disabled value="">Выбрать...</option>
            {% for ts in tsList %}
            <option value="{{ ts.idts }}">{{ ts.brand }} {{ ts.regnumber }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Без машины мы не поедем...</div>
    /div>
</div>

<button type="submit" name="task_id" form="assign_ts" value="{{ items.uid }}" class="btn btn-success">Назначить</button>
</form>

в PHP можно было передавать данные массивом используя 'name=idts[]', например, а как это сделать во flask, jinja ?
Ожидаемое решение:
[
  "d1_id": {"380450","380451","380452"}
  "idts": {"295205011","295205012","295205013"}
  "rl": {"1","2","3"}
]


Как вы передаёте сейчас и как вы получаете сейчас?

Здравствуйте, немного изменил код. Передаю по кнопке. То что необходимо передать получаю из БД

А получаете-то как?

Но как минимум можно сказать, что у request.form есть метод getlist

Да и to_dict(flat=False) тоже есть

Это как раз то, что и было нужно! :) Благодарю Вас!

Я ещё новичок в это деле, благодарю Вас!
